# Preventing an application closing using AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

I have created a script with AppleScript and have exported it as an application. How can I force the application to stay open constantly so the user cannot force-quit it: i.e. how can I open the application again on force-quit?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could save a plist like this as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>test</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Applications/Untitled.app/Contents/MacOS/applet</string>
    <key>RunOnLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It can be loaded with `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist` or by logging out and back in.

Comment: This is a good solution but of course a launchd process can be disabled as well. Basically if a user wants to disable an app and is sophisticated enough and has the proper credentials there's nothing to prevent him from disabling it. The best way would be to ensure the user does not have admin privileges.